# Mapping raw GPS data to Openstreetmap's Node/Way/Relation

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, software-recommendations, map-matching

I have a bunch of raw GPS data points which constitute trips.
I want to add semantic information to those data points. For example I'd like to be able to say that a trip consisted of taking street A, B and C.

With Openstreetmap I can download nodes and ways for a bounding box, which are again described through a bunch of nodes (lat/lng) points.

I actually have all the information I need to map my points to those of Openstreetmap. But reality is messy and my GPS data is not perfect, has outliers and goes off the road.

What is a good approach to calculate which ways or even relations belong to my GPS data?

What is the research done in this area?

Is there already a library that does all the work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can find some hints and solutions in [Digitalizing GPX Points or How to Track Vehicles With GraphHopper](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/digitalizing-gpx-points-or-how-to-track-vehicles-with-graphhopper/) by the developer of the OSM-based routing solution Graphhopper.

His project with your aim is called Map Matching

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is a good map-matching algorithm. There are very few available off the self: see explanation and description on [OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/Travel_Time_Analysis/MatchGPX2OSM). In case you're interested in simply using an API for that purpose, have a look at TraxMatching on my profile.

Comment: I was trying to use the linked to tool. It seems to be outdated. When I run it with any size of a osm file I get an `Error: Value too large or too small` message. This seems to be a general problem, since OSM has recently started to add ids that are bigger than what fits an int32. [Link](https://code.google.com/p/traveltimeanalysis/issues/detail?id=1) offers a solution